# Page security dependent on groups in symfony 1.4

Tags: security, symfony-1.4

1. Can we control/give our page security depending the user groups in symfony 1.4.
2. How can I manage actions on groups in symfony 1.4 not for the pages?
3. Can I give security in plugins module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in your action using [setSecurityConfiguration](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/action/sfAction.class.php#L361) with sth like that:

```
$security = $this->getSecurityConfiguration();
$actionName = strtolower($this->getActionName());
// here you check the groups associated to the user
if ($this->getUser()->hasGroups('foo'))
{
  $security[$actionName]['is_secure'] = true; // or false
  $this->setSecurityConfiguration($security);
}
```

You can give security to any modules (including in a plugin) by putting this into the `config/security.yml` file:

```
all:
  is_secure:   true
```

But please give us more information about *pages*?

Comment: Thank you jok for your advice. I have another question, what is the difference between your suggested way and using the credential to secure pages?

Comment: It's more easy to handle secure page using credential instead of groups. Because, groups aren't part of the security.yml file. If you can handle secure page using credential, do it :) http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_action_security